# Can't execute Titanium Studio on Windows 8

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I installed Titanium Studio properly and when I execute it, gives me an error like this

```
"Failed to load the JNI shared library C:\Program files\Java\JDK 1.7.0_17\bin\...\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"
```

**NOTE: I have java 64bit version.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be the issue with the SDK. In order to run Titanium Studio and the Titanium Mobile SDK successfully, your system environment must meet the following condition

> For Windows, the 32-bit version of Java JDK is required regardless of
>   whether Titanium is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit system.

Please read [System Requirements](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Quick_Start-section-29004949_QuickStart-SystemRequirements) before installing the Titanium Studio.
I hope this will help you